# Is there a way to not repeat all these `From<>` for enums given that the values will be always the same?

Tags: rust, enums

I have two crates. In crate `one`:

```rust
pub struct Identity {
    id: String,
    role: Role,
}

pub enum Role {
    USER,
    ADMIN,
    PROJECT,
    // many other

}
```

In crate `two`:

```rust
pub struct IdentityPublic {
    id: String,
    role: RolePublic,
}

#[derive(async_graphql::Enum, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum RolePublic {
    USER,
    ADMIN,
    PROJECT,
    // many other
}

impl From<RolePublic> for one::Role {
    fn from(o: RolePublic) -> Self {
        match o {
            RolePublic::USER => one::Role::USER,
            RolePublic::ADMIN => one::Role::ADMIN,
            RolePublic::PROJECT => one::Role::PROJECT,
            // many other
        }
    }
}

impl From<one::Role> for RolePublic {
    fn from(o: one::Role) -> Self {
        match o {
            one::Role::USER => RolePublic::USER,
            one::Role::ADMIN => RolePublic::ADMIN,
            one::Role::PROJECT => RolePublic::PROJECT,
            // many other
        }
    }
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to not repeat all that `From<>` for enums given that **the values will be always the same**?
2. I think I cannot use the enum `one::Role` directly in crate `two` because I need to use `#[derive(async_graphql::Enum]` for it (and I cannot modify the crate `one`). **Or is there a way to do it?**

Comment: `one::Role::PROJECT` doesn't exist though. This can't be your real code.

Comment: It’s an example…

Comment: [Wrapping a remote enum](https://async-graphql.github.io/async-graphql/en/define_enum.html#wrapping-a-remote-enum)

Comment: I̶f̶ ̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶l̶a̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶m̶a̶y̶b̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶a̶c̶r̶o̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t No need to write your own. async_graphql already provides it, as given in @cdhowie's link.